# how to sum two table "tk_xts" by date

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I need to sum two times series tables`

```
df1 <- data.frame(date =c("20191228","20191229","20191230","20191231"), value=c(1,2,3,4), income= c(12,14,51,12))
df1$date<-ymd(df1$date)
df1ts <- tk_xts(df1,data_var =date)
df2 <- data.frame(date =c("20191226","20191227","20191228","20191229"), value=c(4,5,6,7), income= c(14,11,53,13))
df2$date<-ymd(df2$date)
df2ts <- tk_xts(df2,data_var =date)
```

I want to get this

```
df3ts       value
2019-12-26   4
2019-12-27   5
2019-12-28   7
2019-12-29   10
2019-12-30   3
2019-12-31   4
```

What kind of funtion I need to apply to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rbind the dataframes and use aggregate.

```
library("tidyverse")
rbind(df1,df2) %>%
  aggregate(. ~ date, ., FUN=sum)
```

If you only want the column 'value', replace the first '.' with 'value'.